# How to set keyboardAppearance and inputView?.backgroundColor to dark at the same time?

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker, uikeyboard

I have `datePicker` that I set as `inputView` of `textField`.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    var datePicker: UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
        datePicker.setValue(UIColor.white, forKeyPath: "textColor")
        textField.inputView = datePicker

        textField.keyboardAppearance = .dark
        textField.inputView?.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.07627698034, green: 0.1097967997, blue: 0.1355849206, alpha: 1)
    }

}
```

I want to have dark toolbar and dark UIDatePicker's background at the same time. But, actually, `textField.inputView?.backgroundColor` doesn't work.
[image]

But if I comment `textField.keyboardAppearance = .dark`, the background of datepicker changes:

[image]

How to fix?

Answer (score 1):

I think with `datePicker`, you don't need this `toolBar`. You can get rid of it as below,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
    datePicker.setValue(UIColor.white, forKeyPath: "textColor")
    textField.inputView = datePicker

    datePicker.backgroundColor = .black
    textField.inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups = []
    textField.inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups = []
}
```

If you want `toolBar` also then you can set a custom `toolBar` with `black` background `color` as below,

```
let toolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50))
toolbar.barTintColor = .black
toolbar.isTranslucent = false // Set to true to give some contrast. 

textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
```